# best practise for ASP.NET Lifecycle in regards to data loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I have a question regarding the best practises in terms of data loading with ASP.NET and C#

As an overview, we have a web page that uses a supporting web service to obtain an fairly large XML file.  That file is then translated into client side JavaScript for use of loading ListViews.

```
protected string clientSideJavaScripts;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code goes here to submit a request and receive an XML Response from the web service
    // code goes here to set clientSideJavaScripts = translated Java Script from the XML Document
    // other code goes here
}
```

The ASP file has something along the lines of:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript>
       <%=clientSideJavaScripts%>
    </scrpit>
</head>

...
```

However additionally there are several buttons on the form that cause postbacks.  These are not directly related to the javascript above.

Everything works well, however I believe (with my limited knowledge of the ASP.NET lifecycle), that that webservice is getting called every postback.  So every time anyone clicks on of the few asp:buttons on the webpage, it is doing the overhead of loading that file regardless of the nature of the button, since a postback will cycle through the stages of the lifecyce from Init up to and past the postback event handling.

The obvious thing to do would be to not call the webservice on postback.  I.E:

```
protected string clientSideJavaScripts;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
       // code goes here to submit a request and receive an XML Response from the web service
       // code goes here to set clientSideJavaScripts = translated Java Script from the XML Document
    }
    // other code goes here
}
```

However the result of that is that the server side string 'clientSideJavaScripts' no longer gets instanciated, and therefore client side no longer gets the required javascript after tje first postback.

I am sure that I am missing an obvious (and probably common) method to deal with the persistancy of the javascript in a case like this, however I don't know of it and therefore I am looking to anyones advice regarding this.  What would be the best practise to ensure that the Webservice is only called once?

I am also using AJAX and JQuery Mobile, if that makes any difference

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly you could either add the results of the webservice call to the session (not recommended if it's a lot of data) or you could insert it into the cache (something like `Cache.Insert(...)`). A third option might be to somehow store it in a database once it's been retrieved from the webservice, and for subsequent calls get it from the database (maybe cleanup after the session ends). 

Try to trace your call to the page to verify what is being called and what isn't (you could also use Fiddler).

Comment: are you saying you don't want the JavaScript loaded on post backs? I think you need to load it every page request (not sure if that is what you are asking).

Comment: I only need the javascript to be loaded (via the webservice) the first time someone lands on the page.  After that I would like it to remain persistent through postbacks, rather than hitting the webservice on every callback.

Comment: Also, Gorgsenegger's suggestion of putting it into session might possibly work.  I will investigate

Comment: As I said above, it might work, but you should try to avoid putting huge amounts of data in your session.

Comment: What's the status, did one of the approaches above work?